# How to clear lcd with a push button in atmega32

Tags: avr, c, port

i write this code for atmega32 in which `PORTD is out put to the LCD` and `PIN0 of PORTA is an input` which i want to active with a push button.This is my code(main):

```
void main(void)
{
    PORTA=0x00;
    DDRA=0xFE;
    PORTD=0x00;
    DDRD=0x00;
lcd_init();
lcd_clear();
lcd_goto(0,0);
lcd_puts("Emad Helmi") ;    
if(PORTA.0 == 0)
{
    lcd_clear() ;    
}
}
```

i have defined the functions above before my main.but with this code,in Proteus whenever i push the button, nothing happend and the lcd didnt clear!
How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried holding the button down while it starts? Because as it is, your code checks the button *once* and then *ends* before you likely have time to press it. Read about "interrupts" to learn how to make this work correctly.

Comment: and also this is my proteus workspace image: [HERE](http://i67.tinypic.com/206btsj.png)

Comment: @Samuel : I also put the if statement in a while(1) block but still not working.

Comment: You need to read the status on PINA, PORTA is for writing. You will also likely need a pull-up resistor. I don't know if your device has internal pull-ups that can be enabled.

Comment: I thought that `settin DDRD=0x00;` makes all the pins of port-d inputs.

Comment: I'm probably mistaken, but when read the spec sheet, my understanding is `PORTx` is for enabling the internal pullup resistors.   `DDRx` is for setting the pins for input/output.   `PINxn` is for reading/writing directly to the I/O pins

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

First off, you only check the condition once, i.e. when you start running the code. So for that I'm adding a while(1) loop.

Second, you have already put your PORTA=0x00, which means you've allotted them a LOW already. If you've already made them LOW, there seems to be no point of checking their status.

I'm not able to view the proteus image file you attached in the comments above. So, I'm assuming that the switch connects the pin to ground. If the switch connects to 5V then change the if condition to PINA.0 == 1;

```
void main(void)
{
    //PORTA=0x00; //If you already made them LOW, there won't be
    DDRA=0xFE;    //any point of checking their status.
    PORTD=0x00;
    DDRD=0x00;
    lcd_init();
    lcd_clear();
    lcd_goto(0,0);
    lcd_puts("Emad Helmi") ;    
    while (1)
    {
        if(PINA.0 == 0) //whenever you want to read the status
        {               //you access the PIN register and not PORT
            lcd_clear() ;    
        }
    }
}
```

If it still doesn't work then try to access PINA as a whole. Change the if condition to

```
if  (PINA == 0x00)
```

but if you do this remember to change individual PORTS to LOW. i.e.

```
PORTA.1 = 0;
```

and so on to PORTA.7 .

Answer (score 1):

if you're writing this code on codevision avr :

```
#include <mega32.h>
#include <alcd.h>
void main(void)
    {
    DDRA=0xFE;//this makes PINA.0 as input
    DDRD=0xFF;//if you want to make ports as output you need to set their DDR
    lcd_init(x);//x is the columns of the lcd you use
    lcd_clear();
    lcd_gotoxy(0,0);//in codevision avr this is the instructure
    lcd_puts("Emad Helmi") ; 
    while(1)//you need to put that condition you're using in a while(true) so it's checked whenever the micro is working
       {
       if(PINA.0 == 0){lcd_clear() ;}//if you're using the A.0 as input you must write PINA.0 , PORTA.0 means you're setting it from micro not from outside
       }
    }
```

another thing to take care of is if you're using Codevision avr , in order to set up the lcd you have to go to configure project->C compiler->liberaries->alphanumeric lcd.
this program writes Emad Helmi and whenever the A.0 is cleared , the lcd is cleared and stays clear forever .